# F# passing none to function, getting null as parameter value

Tags: .net, f#

This is really weird and I fear I have just done something dumb but I can't figure it out.

I'm passing `None` to the function `some` as the first parameter but when the function executes, the value of `parentNode` is null (I'm not concerned with it printing null for `None`, the function parameter value IS null not `None`). I end up getting a null reference error on the print function line because parentNode is null. I've tried to tuple the args and change the order but that didn't help. I have a sneaking suspicion that this has something to do with currying but I'm at a loss...

I had to replace the real url value with an empty string for company issues but it is a url to an xsd if that helps

Here is the code:

```
#light
open System
open System.Xml
open System.Net
open System.Collections.Generic

type StartResult =
    | Parameters of XsdParserParameters
    | Xsd of Xsd

and Xsd(text) =
    let rows = new List<string>()

    member this.Text
        with get() = text

    member this.Rows
        with get() = rows

and XsdParserParameters() =
    let mutable url = ""

    member this.Url
        with get() = url
        and set(value) = url <- value

    member this.Start() =
        try
            use client = new WebClient()
            let xsd = client.DownloadString(this.Url)
            StartResult.Xsd(Xsd(xsd))
        with e ->
            StartResult.Parameters(this)

let processor () =
    let parameters = XsdParserParameters()
    parameters.Url <- ""
    match parameters.Start() with
    | StartResult.Parameters(xpparams) ->
        //some error
        ()
    | StartResult.Xsd(xsd) ->

        let rec some (parentNode : XmlNode option) (node : XmlNode) =
            let a = ()

            for subNode in node.ChildNodes do
                match subNode.LocalName with
                | "complexType" ->
                    xsd.Rows.Add(
                        sprintf
                            "%O~%s~%d~%d~%s~%s~%O" 
                            parentNode 
                            subNode.Value 
                            1 
                            1 
                            (subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value)
                            "" 
                            false)
                    some (Some(subNode)) subNode 
                | "sequence" ->
                    some parentNode subNode 
                | "element" ->
                    xsd.Rows.Add(
                        sprintf 
                            "%O~%s~%d~%d~%s~%s~%O" 
                            parentNode 
                            subNode.Value 
                            1 
                            1 
                            (subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value) 
                            "" 
                            false)
                    some (Some(subNode)) subNode 
                | _ ->
                    ()

        let xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xsd.Text)

        some (None) (xdoc.DocumentElement)

processor()

printfn "Done..."
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Comment: What line are you getting a null reference exception on? `sprintf "%O" null` should work just fine, and I don't see any other reference to `parentNode`, are you sure that is where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's the way F# prints out `None`:

```
> sprintf "%O" None;;
val it : string = "<null>"
```

You can easily write a custom `sprintf` function for `option` type, for example:

```
let sprintOption v = 
    if Option.isNone v then "None" else sprintf "%A" v
```

Comment: That's fine and expected. the problem is that the first parameter doesn't get "none" it gets null. I updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 4):

`Option<'T>` ([source on Github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3093)) uses the attribute [`[<CompilationRepresentation([CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)>]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370528.aspx) which causes the nullary case (`None`, in this instance) to be represented by `null` at run-time.

Comment: Why does this work: > printfn "%O" None;; <null>? Should that error out with a null reference too? And what about match statements? Can I match on None, null or both?

Comment: @Brad: Because `printf` checks for null and prints "<null>" before attempting to call `ToString()`. This also works: `printfn "%O" null`.

Comment: @Brad: Yes, you can match on `None`/`null`.

Comment: Try: `Some(1).Value` and `(None : int option).Value` and also `().ToString()`