# F# Is this a bug in Option.map

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-data

Given the following code:

```
let mapOption (f : ('a -> 'b)) (x : 'a option) =
    match x with
    | Some x -> Some(f(x))
    | None -> None

let mapOptions (f : ('a -> 'b)) (xs : 'a option list) : 'b option list =
    xs
    |> List.map (fun (x : 'a option) -> mapOption f x)

let myList = [None; Some 1; Some 2; None]

let a = myList |> mapOptions (fun x -> x + 2)

let b = myList |> List.map(fun x-> x |> Option.map(fun y -> y + 2))
```

Why is the result for a and b equal to :

`[null; Some 3; Some 4; null]` or `val it : int option list = [null; Some 3; Some 4; null]`

Should it not be:

```
[None; Some 3; Some 4; None]
```

Comment: This behaviour (that `None=null`) is explicitly documented in the spec.  Some more discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435052/f-passing-none-to-function-getting-null-as-parameter-value

Answer (score 7):

`None` is represented by `null` in the CLR. You can see that by experimenting with FSI:

```
> [Some 3; None];;
val it : int option list = [Some 3; null]
```

It still works, though::

```
> [Some 3; None] |> List.choose id;;
val it : int list = [3]
```

So `[null; Some 3; Some 4; null]` is the same as `[None; Some 3; Some 4; None]`:

```
> a = [None; Some 3; Some 4; None];;
val it : bool = true
```

where `a` is the value from the OP.